# How can add links to a header element inline with bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm ussing bootstrap and want to have in the header of a section a link (button) to edit it (like wikipedia [edit] section links).

This is what I have, but its bad aligned (the button is below the text):

```
<h3>
  <span>Details</span>
  <span>
    <a class="btn pull-right" href="/edit">Edit</a>
  </span>
</h3>
```

Is some better way to handle this? *(I'm almost sure that I missed the path)*

Comment: I think you could try to look at http://ink.sapo.pt/typography#nav-headings to achieve that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The align problem was because I was adding the `pull-right` class (floating) directly to the button, instead of that I have to float a wrapper.

```
<h3>
    Details
    <span class="actions">
        <a class="btn" href="/edit">Edit</a>
    </span>
</h3>
```

then, I need to add:

```
.actions {
    float: right;
}
```

And the button align properly as it is not floating anymore.
[This is the working fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/eloyesp/x5Jkj/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<h3>
  <span>
    <a class="btn pull-right" href="/edit">Edit</a>
  </span>
  <span>Details</span>
</h3>
```

Comment: same result. May be I have to add some special margin to `h3 a.btn`

Comment: ..any chance to make a fiddle?

Comment: I can, but not sure how... the main problem is that I was asking for a more *correct* way to do it, not really to fix the visual.